# How to wrap a responsive web app that uses ADFS auth into a native iOS/Android app using only bluemix services?

Tags: android, ios, xpages, ibm-cloud, adfs

The following idea is in our heads and we did not find out how to realize it.

We have a responsive web application that is based on a domino server using xpages. The service authenticates using SAML against our adfs 2.0 service.

We want to use native mobile apps to improve the mobile web app it two disciplines:
1. use notifications to alert users about tasks and events
2. Store the password in a secure way on the device so it won't be asked every time you use the app.

The web app stays on that domino server and is used as is.

I thought this should be possible using only bluemix services.

But how?

We do not want to develop native apps by ourselves so apache Cordova came in our minds. That or a similar solution should enable us to provide native mobile apps with in app stored passwords (or tokens or even touchID logon) and mobile notifications.

Which is the best bluemix practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernd,
you have a rather large set of technology moving parts here :-). Let me pick them into pieces:

1. Domino: you need something outside of Bluemix for storing the NSF, like a Softlayer Domino server. That will be key to the solution.
2. mobile app: Cordova is right, but look one step further and have a look at Ionic. It uses Cordova under the hood. You can add it to your app as is, or use IBM Mobile first foundation
3. Push notifications: there's a service for it in Bluemix
4. Authentication: there's a service for it

What I would do:

- on the Domino server holding the NSFs deploy a OSGi plugin you write extending Domino Access Services that reads/writes the data you are interested in JSON. Use the OpenNTF Domino Api (ODA) to make your life easier
- configure the server to only talk to Bluemix. I would use VPN technology for that - Bluemix has a service for that
- Now the fun part: configure Domino to accept the WAS headers for user identity. Securing Domino in the step before is ESSENTIAL since hitting it direct would now allow to spoof identity. This is why ONLY your Bluemix VPN shall hit it
- Now build your app layer in Bluemix using Liberty or Node.js (I would use Node.js since passport, a Node module, has the most authentication options) that handles auth using the Bluemix services and sets the header when talking to Domino
- Make sure you use a web worker in your mobile app to take the network out of the user experience

That's roughly it. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, Stephan for your reply.
Our aim is to deploy the responsive xpages web app wrapped in an app, not to redesign the whole app functions in ionic or another framework.
So what we have to find out is how can a mobile app authenticate with the service so that the web app loads in an authenticated state?

Main task for the native app is auth and push notification.

Comment: Bernd. There are a few contradictions in your statement: a NATIVE app is written in ObjectiveC, Java or Swift. A responsive app is usually a HTML app.

Comment: So deliver a Webapp inside an app is a squaring of a circle. You are better off wrapping your app into a little ionic wrapper

Comment: We started with ionic and got first results. On iPhone there are a lot of scrolling issues and the well behaving responsive web app does not really feel well inside that ionic iFrame we out it in.

Comment: Do you know how to authenticate with Domino using ionic saved credentials? (Basic or saml or ltpa or ???)

Comment: That's exactly the process I outlined above. Make Domino trust the user header and use a nodejs/passport in front, so any spoofed header gets discarded and let nodejs do the translation from ionic token (afaik jwt) to header

Comment: We got an Ltpa2 token from our domino Server that made an automatic login possible via basic auth with an authentication header and "Basic <base 64 coded username:password>". What is missing is a domsessionauth cookie to use in backend processes for REST calls... any idea?

Comment: Basic auth doesn't create a session cookie. That would be session auth. Ltpa is no condition for basic auth

Comment: Ah, my fault. It was not the DomAuthSessionID we were looking for, but the SessionID. That one was found and now we're up and running. On our SAML idp setup domino server, we added a simple  new website definition on the new /API/ folder which allows to send an authentication header with basic auth and returns ltpa2 and sessionId. So that's done, now some bluemix mobile services have to be involved for push notifications for example.